# Optional Arguments in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Lets suppose there is a stored procedure that has 3 params. Out of all the possibilities, I'm looking to achieve this with a single `WHERE` clause without getting out of control with using `() AND () OR ()` too much...

Example:

```
    //Params
@CITY VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@GENDER VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@AGE VARCHAR(100) = NULL
```

I suppose you can do it using `IF BEGIN ... END` for each Variable if Exists, but that makes the code alot longer than desired..

This method below won't work because its way too long (there are about 10 different fields like this, but the example is only 3.) and i'm not sure if it even directly pulls up distinctive values...

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE 
WHERE (
(CITY=@CITY AND GENDER=@GENDER AND AGE=@AGE)
OR (CITY=@CITY AND GENDER=@GENDER)
OR (GENDER=@GENDER AND AGE=@AGE)
OR (CITY=@CITY AND AGE=@AGE)
OR (CITY=@CITY)
OR (GENDER=@GENDER)
OR (AGE=@AGE)
)
```

Is there an even shorter more efficient way to do this?

If yes, it is preferable for the method to be compatible with JOIN's also.

Comment: Side-note: when defining a `VARCHAR()` - as a parameter to a stored proc or a local variable - should **always** have a **length** defined! Otherwise you might end up with `VARCHAR(1)` strings inadvertently...

Comment: Optional fields meaning if there is no or `NULL` value, then don't show it in the Where clause, is it possible?

Comment: Read this: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Alternatively to the `ISNULL` / `COALESCE` options, you can test the parameters for being null:

```
SELECT NAME  
FROM TABLE  
WHERE  
    (@City IS NULL OR City = @City)
AND 
    (@Gender IS NULL OR Gender = @Gender)
AND 
    (@Age IS NULL OR Age = @Age)
```

Comment: I know it's a bit too late for a comment, but please be careful with this approach as SQL Server does not guarantee the order of the evaluation (it won't for sure do the short-circuit). So you might as well end up SQL Server doing all the unnecessary checks.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: And flushing performance down the hill.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik so what would be a better way of doing this? Thought of dynamic sql but it bring other problems like maintenance, code clearance, etc. There's no other better way?

Comment: Not that I know of at least :) I would use dynamic SQL if it gets complex enough and begins affecting performance

Comment: using OR and Dynamic sql Query lead us to performance hit, It seems the best bet is using IF ..ELSE or Case statement ,I think By this way two execution plan  would be make and would be cached , I  had such a question, please take a look at it for getting started . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386090/building-dynamic-query-using-case-in-where-clause

Comment: it works ok with small results which have to be filtered. but the performance is really bad with joins on large tables. (informix)

Comment: cjk ,  Hello , I was waondering how we do it with if we have to deal with a list like of String ?

Comment: @cjk it make my Query 10x slower!

Answer (score 21):

what about this?

```
SELECT
    NAME
FROM TABLE 
WHERE CITY = COALESCE(@CITY, CITY)
    AND GENDER = COALESCE(@GENDER, GENDER)
    AND AGE = COALESCE(@AGE, AGE)
```

Comment: Beautiful! Hopefully, SQL Server is able to optimize away the conditions if null variables are encountered. Would be interesting to test.

Comment: This is nice, but will not include a record if, say, `CITY` and `@CITY` are both null, because null is not equatable to null (unless `ANSI_NULLS` is set to OFF).

Comment: @MCattle then coalesce to city too. Ex: `COALESCE(CITY, 0) = COALESCE(@CITY, CITY, 0)`

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
    City = IsNull(@City, City) AND
    Gender = IsNull(@Gender, Gender) AND
    Age = IsNull(@Age, Age)
```

OR:

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
    (City = @City OR @City IS NULL) AND
    (Gender = @Gender OR @Gender IS NULL) AND
    (Age = @Age OR @Age IS NULL)
```

Comment: i think your first example may cut it, let me check it out.. brb.

Comment: In regards to the first option....does NULL equal NULL?

Comment: `Select * From Table Where NULL IS NULL` will return all rows. That is ok in this context because it means that you do not want to filter by the argument if you pass it a `NULL` value.

Comment: Yes but Select * From Table Where NULL = NULL will not include the rows with null column values.  Test it out on a table that has a nullable column containing NULLs. e.g:SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
mycolumn = IsNull(null, mycolumn)

Comment: That *City = IsNull(@City, City)* format never occurred to me before. Nice and clean looking.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT NAME   
FROM TABLE   
WHERE       
  City = case when isnull(@City ,'') = '' then City
                        else @City end
AND      
  Gender = case when isnull(@Gender ,'') = '' then Gender
                        else @Gender end
AND  
  Age = case when isnull(@Age ,0) = 0 then Age
                        else @Age end
```

Comment: I doubt that the City=City condition  and in general Column =Column Condition is an ineffective condition , for example null = null could lead us to UNKNOWN and at the other hand if our column would be Not null , we end up with a full scan table for column = column condition .

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this:

```
create procedure myProc
    --Params
@CITY VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@GENDER VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@AGE VARCHAR(100) = NULL
as

SELECT NAME FROM [TABLE]
WHERE ISNULL(CITY,'')=ISNULL(@CITY,ISNULL(CITY,''))
AND ISNULL(GENDER,'')=ISNULL(@GENDER,ISNULL(GENDER,''))
AND ISNULL(AGE,'')=ISNULL(@AGE,ISNULL(AGE,''))
go
```

Assuming the columns in the WHERE clause are nullable, using ISNULL to avoid null comparison.

Comment: uggghhh.. i wanted to avoid doing it that way.. anything like 'IsNull'?