# Optional where clause depending on parameter value

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I want the where statement for this query to be optional depending on what the value of parameter @RetrieveAll is. If @RetrieveAll is false/null the where statement is used, if it is true it should be ignored.

```
    @IncludeErrors bit = 1,
    @IncludeAccess bit = 1,
    @IncludeLogins bit = 1,
    @RetrieveAll bit = NULL
SELECT
 //...
FROM
(

) AS a
WHERE
a.RowNumber BETWEEN @ItemCountStart AND @ItemCountEnd
```

Is there way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optional Arguments in WHERE Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185638/optional-arguments-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 //...
FROM
(

) AS a
WHERE
(a.RowNumber BETWEEN @ItemCountStart AND @ItemCountEnd AND @RetrieveAll IS NULL)
OR
@RetrieveAll IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

```
Select * from Tablename a
Where 
1 = case when isnull(@RetriveAll,0) == 0 then 
        case when a.RowNumber BETWEEN @ItemCountStart AND @ItemCountEnd then 1 else 0 end
    else 1 end
```