# Building Dynamic Query Using Case in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a stored procedure and I want to implement the following query using Case Statement , but I am not sure how to do it .
pseudocode of what I want is provided here :

```
declare @PI_X decimal(18);
declare @PI_y decimal (18);

SELECT F1, F2,F3
FROM TABLE T 
WHERE 
 CASE 
 WHEN @PI_X IS NULL THEN @PI_Y = T.Y
 WHEN @PI_Y IS NULL THEN @PI_X = T.X
```

It seems that using case statement  for *conditions* is not true and its for `values`.

**NOTE:**

I want to run this query in DB2 and SQL server , but really  Data Base vendor is not important for me ,using  ***sql dynamic query*** and **(OR)** in where clause has a performance hit . and I don't want it. I really like to know  how it's  possible to achieve such a logic using case in where clause.

Could you please help me to handle this problem . **Any help and suggestions would be so appreciated .**

Answer (score 2):

The result of a `CASE` expression is a **value**, not an expression. You can't use a `CASE` expression to decide which code will run. You can only use it to choose what value will be used with your code.

In this case, you can accomplish your goal like this:

```
declare @PI_X decimal(18);
declare @PI_y decimal (18);

SELECT F1, F2,F3
FROM TABLE T 
WHERE 1 = 
 CASE 
 WHEN @PI_X IS NULL AND @PI_Y = T.Y THEN 1
 WHEN @PI_X IS NOT NULL AND @PI_Y IS NULL AND @PI_X = T.X THEN 1 
 ELSE 0 END
```

You could also try it like this:

```
declare @PI_X decimal(18);
declare @PI_y decimal (18);

SELECT F1, F2,F3
FROM TABLE T 
WHERE coalesce(@PI_X, T.X) = T.X AND coalesce(@PI_y, T.Y) = T.Y
```

Though this second option might produce unexpected results if `@PI_y` might be something other than `NULL` when `@PI_x` has a value. If you can guarantee one or the other of the two variables will have a value, but never both, then you could also simplify the first option to remove the extra `@PI_X IS NOT NULL AND` part of the expression.

Comment: thank you :), I am so interested in your answer , But I need to test it

Comment: what do you think about this : WHERE T.X = CASE WHEN PI_X IS NOT NULL THEN PI_X ELSE T.X END ADN T.Y = CASE WHEN PI_Y IS NOT NULL THEN PI_Y ELSE T.Y END --------------------------------------------- 
I think this solution has only one disadvantage , because at last we will have a useless condition T.y= T.y or T.x =T.x and I doubt that this has a performance hit or not .what is your idea about this approach ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your question is tagged with both SQL Server AND DB2... But I'll assume SQL Server...

```
declare @PI_X decimal(18);
declare @PI_y decimal (18);

SELECT 
    T.F1, 
    T.F2,
    T.F3
FROM 
    TABLE T 
WHERE 
    (@PI_X = T.X OR @PI_X IS NULL)
    AND ((@PI_y = T.Y OR @PI_y IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE); -- Prevent's the forced scan operation cause by the use of "optional" parameters.
```

Comment: I want to run this query in db2 and sql server , but data base vendor is not important really , I was aware about your solution but using OR causes a full scan table , and I don't know how to prevent it in DB2

Comment: Actually vendor is important. Different RDBMS have different implementations of the SQL syntax. The idea of code portability across platforms is pretty laughable at this point, considering that you're lucky to be able to port your code between different release versions of the same product. The code above will allow a seek operation in SQL Server by using OPTION(RECOMPILE). The only other option is to use dynamic sql, which, IMO, wouldn't be warranted for something as simple as this. As far as DB2... I don't use it myself, so I don't have a clue how it handles optional parameters.

Comment: what do you think about this : 
WHERE 
     T.X = CASE 
              WHEN PI_X IS  NOT NULL THEN  PI_X 
              ELSE  T.X  
              END 

ADN
         T.Y = CASE
             WHEN PI_Y IS NOT NULL THEN PI_Y
            ELSE T.Y 
             END 
---------------------------------------------
I think this solution has only one disadvantage , because at last we will have a useless condition T.y= T.y or T.x =T.x and I doubt that this has a performance hit or not ?

Comment: I think you'll end up with a non-SARGEable query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out putting the if condition which will be readable however increasing the lines of code.

```
if(@PI_X IS NULL)
begin
select 
....
where 
T.Y=@PI_Y
end

else
begin
select 
....
where 
T.X = @PI_X
end
```

Comment: this is exactly the straight solution but you should remember the two part of your select query code to change ,if any changes need to be happened in the feature .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause you could also build 2 separate queries and use `IF...ELSE...` to decide which one to use; something along the lines of what Coder1991 suggested. Or you could use a `UNION ALL` construction to avoid the `IF` and eliminate any branching.

```
SELECT F1, F2,F3
 FROM TABLE T 
WHERE @PI_X IS NULL 
  AND @PI_Y = T.Y

UNION ALL

SELECT F1, F2,F3
  FROM TABLE T 
 WHERE @PI_Y IS NULL 
   AND @PI_X = T.X
```

Comment: thank you for your new approach , its smart , But in this case , I think  Union ALL approach has no advantage over  IF-Else  approach , You need to repeat the Select F1,F2,F3 part of the query at both of them  , and If I have to do that, I, personally, prefer using IF-Else .

Comment: what do you think about this : WHERE T.X = CASE WHEN PI_X IS NOT NULL THEN PI_X ELSE T.X END ADN T.Y = CASE WHEN PI_Y IS NOT NULL THEN PI_Y ELSE T.Y END ---------------------------------------------------I think this solution has only one disadvantage , because at last we will have a useless condition T.y= T.y or T.x =T.x and I doubt that this has a performance hit or not .what is your idea about this approach

Comment: Only way to know for sure is to test it. The query optimizer sometimes turns 'convoluted code' into great performance, but sometimes it 'doesn't get it' for some reason and then you're stuck. Simply run both queries at once and compare their query plan and the time it took them to get there. Keep in mind that sometimes the query with the high cost still turns out to be the fastest one (read: cost != time).