# sql query | handling multiple where conditions with a potential null value

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume the following table:

```
╔═══╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║Property A    ║Property B   ║
╠═══╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ slow         ║low          ║
║ 2 ║ fast         ║high         ║
╚═══╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

User has the option to filter result using either both properties or just one. The input is stored in variables `$p1, $p2`

If both the variables get a value from user I can easily query them like this:

```
select * from table where (propertyA=$p1 and propertyB=$p2)
```

However if one of them gets no value from user, how do I query?
Since the line in the above query `propertyA=$p1` would become false since `$p1` could be null, however the query result should return based on the value of `$p2`.

For example for the input (null,low) the query should return the first record, but with my query, it will not.

This example is just for two properties, I have multiple properties in my table so implementing multiple if conditions would be a hassle.

I was wondering if there is any concise way to go about this.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional Arguments in WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185638/optional-arguments-in-where-clause)

Comment: "User has the option to filter result using either both properties **or** just one." Should your conditions be an `OR` or an `AND`? If they supply both, should conditions match both or either one?

Comment: @Shawn its an AND

Comment: So if they supply both it HAS to be both, correct?

Comment: @Shawn yes, correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic approaches to this problem: 1)dynamically generating the SQL statement, 2) handle NULL with expressions in a static SQL statement

The dynamic approach, if the query is being executed from application...

we start with a static string, what the query is going to look like everytime:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT t.id
           FROM mytable t
         WHERE 1=1';
```

and then decide if we're going to append another condition to the WHERE clause

```
 if( $p1 !== '' ) {
    $sql .= ' AND t.propertyA = :p1';
 }
 if( $p2 !== '' ) {
    $sql .= ' AND t.propertyB = :p2';
 }

 // prepare the SQL statement
 $sth=$pdo->prepare($sql);

 // conditionally bind values to the placeholders
 if( $p1 !== '' ) {
    $sth->bindValue(':p1',$p1);
 }
 if( $p2 !== '' ) {
    $sth->bindValue(':p2',$p2);
 }
```

The downside of dynamic SQL is that with more complex problems, it can get overly tricky to properly construct the SQL statement. With just conditions in the `WHERE` clause, it's a viable approach.

Another downside is the wide variety of SQL statements we can end up producing, and ensuring that each variation will have a suitable execution plan gets complicated.  With only two optional conditions in the WHERE clause, we've got a very manageable total of 4 variations...

Oh, the reason for including the condition `1=1` in the `WHERE` clause doesn't impact the statement; the optimizer is smart enough to figure out that its true for every possible row, so that condition gets tossed.  What that buys us is when we're appending to the `WHERE` clause, we eliminate the need to check "is this the first condition in the WHERE clause?" so we know whether to append `WHERE` or `AND` to the statement.

---

The second approach is to use static with SQL, using some expressions.

As an example, assuming propertyA and propertB are character type columns:

```
$sql = "SELECT t.id 
          FROM mytable t
         WHERE t.propertyA <=> IFNULL(NULLIF(:p1,''),t.propertyA) 
           AND t.propertyB <=> IFNULL(NULLIF(:p2,''),t.propertyB)"; 

$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':p1',$p1);
$sth->bindValue(':p2',$p2);
```

If we supply a non-zero length string for `:p1`, then the `NULLIF` function returns `:p1`, and the IFNULL function returns `:p1`. It will be as if we had just written:

```
 t.propertyA <=> :p1
```

If we supply a zero length string for `$p1` (for placeholder `:p1`) then the SQL  `NULLIF` function will return a NULL. And in turn, the `IFNULL` function will return `t.propertyA`, so the statement will be comparing `propertyA` to itself, so the net result will be as we had written

```
AND t.propertyA <=> t.propertyA
```

or just

```
AND 1=1
```

(The difference is that the optimizer won't discard our condition, since the optimizer doesn't know what value we're going to supply for :p1 when the execution plan is prepared.

NOTE: The `<=>` spaceship operator is a NULL-safe comparsion. It's guaranteed to return TRUE or FALSE (and not return NULL), unlike the standard equality comparison (`=`) which returns NULL when either (or both) of the values being compared are NULL.

This:

```
foo <=> bar
```

is essentially shorthand for the equivalent:

```
foo = bar OR ( foo IS NULL AND bar IS NULL )
```

If we are guaranteed that `propertyA` will never be NULL (for example, by an explicit NOT NULL constraint in the table definition), we can forgo the spaceship operator and just use a plain equality comparison.

The downside of this approach is a less intuitive SQL statement; the uninitiated might be scratching their heads over it.  So we are going to want to leave a comment in the code, explaining that the matching condition is condition, if  `:p1` is empty string, there's no comparison to `:p1`.

We could use different syntax to achieve the same result, for example, using the more portable ANSI-standards compliant `COALESCE` function in place of `IFNULL`, and a `CASE` expression in place of `NULLIF`. (That would require us to supply `$p1` to an extra placeholder, writing it like we did, we only have to supply `$p1` one time.)

---

But those are the two basic patterns. Pick your poison.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate enlightenment!

Comment: Note that with both of these patterns we've reserved a zero-length string to be a special value. That is, neither of these patterns (as implemented in this answer) support doing a `propertyA = ''` condition in the query. (We're relying a "special value" to represent "no search". The question specifically asked about NULL, we could adjust the queries to use NULL as the special value. In PHP, we could use a `is_null` test in place of the `!==` comparison.  And for the second pattern, we would adjust the SQL, and bind a NULL  `bindValue(':p1',$p1,PDO::PARAM_NULL)`.

Answer (score 1):

If both properties are strings, you may use wildcard `'%'`

```
select * from table where (propertyA like $p1 and propertyB like $p2)
```

Comment: i think you misread the question.
wildcard would give the same result in case one of the variable is null

Comment: I meant, if the variable is null, your input should be `('%', 'low')` not `(null,'low')`. You could also use [`COALESCE($p1, '%')`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Well query is a string afterall, you need to first format the string, based on conditions then when final string is ready, execute the query.

```
function chechForProperty($variable, $colName)
{
      if(isset($variable) || $variable != '')
      {
           return $colName."=".$variable." and ";
      } 
      return "";
}


$query = "select * from table where (";
$query .= checkForProperty($p1,'propertyA');
$query .= checkForProperty($p2,'propertyB');
$query .= checkForProperty($p3,'propertyC');
$query = substr($query,0,-5);
$query .= ");";

// now execute the query, I am just printing
print_r($query);
```

Hope this helps, thanks